# How to setup a route on an Arris router

Tags: networking, router, routing

After reading the first half of this support article (https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12116176/rv042-082-016-sx300500-switch-open-discussion), I was able to setup my Cisco SG300-10 managed switch to look like my desired scheme: [Desired Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNrKA.png)

Basically, I want anything connected directly to the router (Arris NVG589) to have an IP of 192.168.1.xxx and everything connected to ports 1-8 on the switch (which will all be assigned to VLAN10 with port 10 serving as a trunk to the router) to have an IP of 192.168.10.xxx. I plugged a laptop up to one of the ports on the switch and it was assigned a local IP of 192.168.10.1, as desired. However, while connected, it has no internet access. Anything on the default VLAN1 can access the internet, but no access for VLAN10. I suspect there's a missing route from the router to the switch for VLAN10.

After looking all over the router settings menu and the internet, I could not locate an option on the router that simply lets me setup a route to the switch. I looked all over the Web and the general consensus seems to be enabling an IP Passthrough mode for this particular brand of router, but I'm not entirely sure that will accomplish what I need above (or how to set it up).

**How do I configure my router, switch, or both to give VLAN10 access to the internet?** After days of searching and configuring, I suspect that a missing route is the only thing that's not allowing internet access for VLAN 10.

Additional info

- The router has a default gateway of 192.168.1.254
- The switch has a local IP of 192.168.1.178, despite is saying it ends in .253 in the photo.
- The "Entertainment Goodies" in the photo are just a collection of streaming and gaming devices. They should be given an IP of 192.168.10.xxx when plugged into the switch.
- In the end, the desktop and entertainment goodies should be on a different network than the AP and VPN server, but EVERYTHING should have internet access.

Comment: It's not a missing route, it's a missing NAT rule.

Comment: The only thing in the NAT rules my router has to offer is what ports on the firewall to open up, so I'm unsure if that's part of the problem or not.

Comment: Some device has to provide NAT for those devices or they won't be able to access the Internet. If your firewall can't do it and your router can't do it, then they won't get Internet access.